# how to add new observations to a dataframe based on criteria?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a table of results (test.df) for multiple sites over multiple time periods.  One of the soil parameters is split into two parameters (DDT 2 and DDT 4). I want to sum these together and add them back into the dataframe.

I can sum these results like this:

```
test1 <- test %>% 
  select(Sample,Site,Parameter,Value) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Parameter,"DDT")) 

test1 %>% 
  group_by(Sample,Site) %>% 
  count(sum(Value))
```

but I'm not sure how to add them back into the original dataframe

My original dataframe (test.df) looks something like this (but with many more sites and samples)

```
 Sample         Site  Parameter       Value
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 2,4'-DDT   0.010
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 4,4-DDT    0.020
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 4,4 FB     0.020
   2013-01-31   4040  Soil 2,4'-DDT   0.010
   2013-01-31   4040  Soil 4,4-DDT    0.010
   2014-01-27   4040  Soil 4,4 EC     0.020
```

I would like to sum the DDT values for each Site and add back into the table like this:

```
 Sample         Site  Parameter      Value
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 2,4'-DDT  0.010
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 4,4-DDT   0.020
   2014-01-27   3999  Soil 4,4 EC    0.020
   2014-01-27   3999  Total DDT      0.030
   2013-01-31   4040  Soil 2,4'-DDT  0.010
   2013-01-31   4040  Soil 4,4-DDT   0.010
   2014-01-27   4040  Soil 4,4 EC    0.020
   2013-01-31   4040  Total DDT      0.020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this approach may work for you:

```
data<- data.frame(Sample= c("2014-01-27","2014-01-27","2013-01-01","2013-01-01"),
                  SiteID= c(3999,3999,4040,4040),      
                  DetDesc= c("Soil 2,4-DDT", "Soil 4,4-DDT","Soil 2,4-DDT", "Soil 4,4-DDT"),
                  Value= c(0.010, 0.02, 0.010, 0.01)
                  )
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(SiteID, Sample) %>% 
  summarise(Value = sum(Value)) %>%mutate(DetDesc = "Total DDT")%>%
  select(Sample, SiteID, DetDesc, Value ) %>% bind_rows(data)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   SiteID [2]
  Sample     SiteID DetDesc      Value
  <fct>       <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
1 2014-01-27   3999 Total DDT     0.03
2 2013-01-01   4040 Total DDT     0.02
3 2014-01-27   3999 Soil 2,4-DDT  0.01
4 2014-01-27   3999 Soil 4,4-DDT  0.02
5 2013-01-01   4040 Soil 2,4-DDT  0.01
6 2013-01-01   4040 Soil 4,4-DDT  0.01
```

If you want it without grouping by the `Sample` column as well, just remove it.
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks Charles, That worked nicely.  The original df has a number of other columns which I didn't show. I noticed that when I bind_rows back to my original df those attributes are assigned an NA...is there away to retain that information?

Comment: Well if u have the same number of columns in both cases with the same colnames in both cases, then you can do it. You can first cbind() the cases to create vector with the length you want and then rbind()